# How do I correct my character falling through when cloth is enabled on his cape

Tags: cloth-simulation

My character falls through the "stage" when I use cloth on his cape and pin it to the verices. How does one correct this issue? Forgot to add that my character and his cape are one piece

Comment: if the cape and the character are one object, then the character is being cloth simulated as a whole. it then reacts to gravity and falls until it hits a collision object. can you provide the blend file? a simplified version is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are one piece (or mesh) then your character becomes cloth as well, he is not pinned and will therefore fall. You probably dont have a collision modifier set up on the stage as well.

Separate the meshes, add a collision modifier to your stage and the character and parent the cape to your character. That should solve it.

Comment: How does one split a mesh?

Comment: select all vertices of the part you want to separate, then press ctrl+p and choose selected. the mesh is now split